# About complex integration.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I was reading a Physics text book and this formula was given without any proof. It seems like a very basic one but I could find information about it anywhere. Not sure if it has a name or not.
Given a complex number $\phi_\alpha$, how to derive this equation below:
$$
\frac{\mathbb{d}\phi_\alpha^*\cdot\mathbb{d}\phi_\alpha}{2\pi i}=\frac{\mathbb{d}\text{Re}(\phi_\alpha)\cdot \mathbb{d}\text{Im}(\phi_\alpha)}{\pi}
$$
Not sure if this help, but I found this in the closure relation of boson coherent state, that is:
$$
\int \prod _\alpha{\frac{\mathbb{d}\phi_\alpha^*\cdot \mathbb{d}\phi_\alpha}{2\pi i}}e^{-\sum_\alpha{\phi_\alpha^*\phi_\alpha} }  |\phi><\phi|=1
$$
Hope someone could help me explain or point me to some resources that I could read about it.

Comment: If you write $\phi* = A - Bi$ and $\phi = A + Bi$ and then calculate the Jacobian matrix of the transformation the elements are $1, 1, -i, i$ and the determinant is $2i$.

Comment: Ahh yes, the Jacobian. Thank you so much. It really is a basic one. 